# How to implement add_action,do_action functionality in custom php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, plugins

I want to implement the similar functionality like 'add_action','do_action','remove_action' in wordpress in custom php.
Can you please suggest me how can I implement ?

Comment: *in custom php* What does that mean? Isn't WP custom enough for you?

Comment: No. I am not using neither wp or any php framework . But i want to implement this wp hooks in basic custom php by using php core functions or php clases.

Comment: Why don't you then use WP or copy the source code for this functions ?

Comment: Can you tell me which functions I have to copy from wp ?

Comment: These which you want: `add_action`, ...

Comment: I just want to know how the add_action function works. i.e what is the functional flow in wp.

Comment: Download the source code: https://wordpress.org/download/source/ search for the function declaration and study it

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you very much for giving me your valuable time. I think you are not getting my point. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

add_action, do_action could be some functions.

You can create your own functions and use them, like getUrl(), colorMyText("Blabla"), ...

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Simple exemple :

```
function colorMyText($string, $color){
    $colored_string = '<FONT COLOR="'.$color.'">'.$string.'</FONT>';
    return $colored_string;
}
```

Then, just write

```
echo colorMyText("Hello world!", "red");
echo colorMyText("</br> I'm fine!", "#0000FF");
```

This is a basic function, but you can do what you want, and so, no repeat the same code X times. 
Wordpress and many CMS works with functions, like get_header(), ...

Comment: Beside a comment and a piece of a basic php tutorial i don't see a answer here.

Comment: He wants to create his own functions, so I explain how creating functions.